# Way other than Ctrl+C to stop a command?

Tags: c, command, kill, ctrl

I tried to run a script in Terminal that led to the following recurring code:
[Recurring code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDFh9.png)

When I try to press "Ctrl+C" this will stop the command from running on the screen, but if I open Terminal again, the command recurs over and over again. I tried various scripts to kill the process, but nothing is working. Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: You have some script running some broken stuff on a shell startup. Look and clean up the `.bashrc` and/or `.bash_profile`.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure exactly how to do this. Can you help me with exactly which commands I should enter?

Comment: You might get an answer at [unix.se].

Comment: Have you tried `Ctrl-Z` followed by `kill -9 %1`? This assumes that you don't have any other jobs backgrounded and then force kills the script.

Comment: I just tried this but it is not working. The response returns as : -bash: kill: %1: no such job

Comment: Did you edit your `.profile` or `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` file recently (or a file used by one those scripts)? When you hit Control-C, do you get a shell prompt back? If you get a shell prompt back and you edited a file recently, then you can re-edit the file. If you don't get a shell prompt back, you'll need to find a way to start up a terminal without running the start-up scripts; the terminal program may have options you can set to prevent the shell being started as a login shell. In future, if you edit the control files, keep a terminal open, possibly editing the files, while you play.